# Why can we permanently avoid register spilling by reassigning variables in C code?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, cpu-registers, cpython

**Summarized questions:**

1. How do I know when to reassigning the variable in C code to avoid register spilling? Does the answer depend on the CPU structure of target machines and the compiler?
2. If I add some new variables in the original code, should I check the line for avoiding register spilling is still useful?

In CPython, I found [a line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/29d018aa63b72161cfc67602dc3dbd386272da64/Objects/setobject.c#L94) trying to avoid register spilling by reassigning the variable. The change of the line can be traced to [the commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/438f9134cfb7a3b68cff9de9f730f42f68c2cc94) created in 2015. I am curious about the principle of the line.

When a user runs Python, there are many data and codes loading into the memory or the registers. Why that line of code to prevent from register spilling still works if other parts of the code of CPython are changed? Continuously, CPython is built on various CPU architectures and different operating systems. Why the comment of the commit just mentioned the types of the compilers?

Comment: I'd assume that whoever made that change is clueless, and that either their changes  were removed by compiler's optimizer and made no difference at all (likely) or made performance of the generated code worse (unlikely).

Comment: It's hard to generically prevent this when various systems vary so widely in the number of registers they have available.  Also spilling registers is not exactly the end of the world in terms of performance hits.

Comment: The comment says "micro-optimization based on observed compiler output".  So the author has decided to reorder his code based on the compiler(s) he was using at the time.  This is a valid strategy for a time-critical loop, especially since in this case he didn't really change the semantics of the function, he just re-ordered some intermediate operations. However, this is in no way  "permanent" -  future compiler upgrades or even different compile flags are not guaranteed to preserve this optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the code generator runs out of registers in which to hold intermediate and frequently used values, it *spills registers* by writing them memory, typically in an area allocated from the stack.  In general, this is a low-cost operation and is highly dependent upon the number of registers in your cpu, the options given to the compiler, and the version of the compiler itself.

You should strive to write clear code, not try to reverse engineer the code generator.  Often the code generator will reward you for this by generating pretty good code.   When you run into performance problems, the profiler should guide you to the code that needs revisited.  Improvements are typically made structurally or algorithmically.  Code tricks to improve the generated code often revolve around revealing information to the compiler; such as a value it thinks is dynamic is really static, or arranging data structures to better utilize cache resources.

If you have to reverse engineer the code generator, you really might as well rewrite the sequence in machine language -- there is at least a manual on machine language, where as compiler hacks are always tribal knowledge.   How do you know which bits to rewrite in machine language -- look to the profiler again.

Comment: I don't think they went as far as to "reverse engineer the code generator". I have done similar optimisations before just from the disassembly shown by my IDE. Find a specific function in the profiler, look at the function, no obvious optimisation, look at the disassembly and maybe it didn't inline something in a loop I expected, or unroll, use SSE how I wanted, or such. Id much rather try and "prompt" the compiler into doing it, worst case intrinsics, than rewrite the whole thing in assembler (which it will never optimise around, inline, future porting, etc.).

Comment: Low-cost operations involve registers only. Memory loads or stores are the opposite of low-cost operations, that's why people strive to avoid them. Allocating registers while minimising stack stores/loads is a non-trivial unsolved problem as of 2023. Writing clear code is best practice, but has little influence on register allocation.

Comment: Writing convoluted code that aspires to avoid register spilling is little better than praying to a god you have no ken of.   The engine that controls register allocation ignores pathetic attempts to subvert it, and analyses the local, and sometimes global data flow, permitting registers as caches as it can determine such caching does not interfere with correctness.  The worst code for a generator to deal with is that which tries to cleverly trick the generator into better code.  At least that is what the last 40 years of writing system code has taught me.